# URL WeWrite module bug, not redirecting to HTTPS, case sensitive issue in IIS

Tags: url-rewriting, case-sensitive, iis-8, virtual-directory

I had a web application directory named with capitals like this:

- http://domain.com/IT

I then renamed the physical folder to use all-lowercase like so:

- http://domain.com/it

I have a URL rewrite rule in the web root that forces HTTPS protocol when HTTP is used.  However, after renaming the subfolder, there is strange behavior.

- http://domain.com/IT     //FAIL: allows http
- http://domain.com/it     //SUCCESS: redirects to https
- http://domain.com/iT     //SUCCESS: redirects to https
- http://domain.com/It     //SUCCESS: redirects to https

At first, it looks like it occurs only when the original all-uppercase name was used, but the behavior is more complex than it appears, because the subfolders case alters the behavior with similar results that also violate the original assumption.

In both cases, the directories originally used capital letters when set up as web applications, so they both had virtual directories with capital letters.

I simply made the directories lowercase.  To reset the virtual directory, I simply right clicked the app in IIS manager, removed the web app, then re-added it.

- http://domain.com/IT/team/     FAIL: allows http
- http://domain.com/IT/Team/     SUCCESS: redirects to https (surprise!)
- http://domain.com/it/Team/     SUCCESS: redirects to https
- http://domain.com/it/team/     SUCCESS: redirects to https

It even redirects properly if I target a non-existent directory

- http://domain.com/IT/nothing   SUCCESS: redirects to https  (non-existent directory)
- http://domain.com/it/nothing   SUCCESS: redirects to https  (non-existent directory)

I just cannot figure out why it's failing to direct in those two particular cases, the first being when the target is the web application root with it's original letter case, and the second being when it targets a subfolder in the web app with the original case of the web app, but only the correct new letter case of the subfolder.

Comment: Clearing my web browser cache has made the problem go away, but this doesn't explain why the server is allowing an insecure HTTP request through, when the rewrite rule should intercept it.